# App engine "hello world" not working (java)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

i downloaded the google app engine plugin for eclipse and i opened a new web project.
but when i try to run this project (untouched) the eclipse say:
"The server is running at http://localhost:8888/"
so i opened the browser and  i get 101 error 
"The connection to localhost was interrupted."

what i did wrong?

here is what the console present:

```
Dec 21, 2011 12:10:03 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Dec 21, 2011 12:10:03 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader  readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\sl300\Synca\try2\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Dec 21, 2011 12:10:03 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader   readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\sl300\Synca\try2\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Dec 21, 2011 2:10:04 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
Dec 21, 2011 2:10:04 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
```

(little details: i have windows vista, eclipse Helios Service Release 2.
i tried with jre6 or jre7 )

Comment: Care to show us your code? It's hard to find out what could cause the problem without seeing any code whatsoever.

Comment: All that shows is that the development appserver started normally. If that's all it showed after the connection problem, then you probably do have some sort of local firewall issue. Had it been some sort of coding error, more would have been logged.

Comment: i shut down my firewall and its still isn't working
as for the code - i didn't write anything, the eclipse generate an example of "hello world" in the new project

Answer (score 0):

This can occur because of your 'Hosts File Configuration' or 'Proxy settings' or 'Anti-Virus software on your system' or if you are using web-debugging/http-logging tools like Fiddler or TCPMon. Correct the configuration if it is not properly set and try it again.